Late IRA contribution
My wife and I filed jointly for the first time and were planning to contribute that maximum for our Roth IRA’s for tax year 2023. However, the deadline has passed. Is there any possible way to still contribute for last year or has that opportunity passed?

No, if you missed the April 15th deadline you're out of luck. See the IRS:

What is the deadline to make contributions?
Your tax return filing deadline (not including extensions). For example, you can make 2022 IRA contributions until April 18, 2023.

